# Flutter web redirect url not changing in AWS

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

Flutter web url not changing when i host it in Aws S3

I host flutter web in S3 and point it's index from php. Content is coming but url not changing. I try to host Flutter web in aws S3 and point it's index from php. After this content is coming but on redirect the url not changing.